# Show Image from sharepoint list

Tags: image, flutter

I'm developing a flutter app where i want to show images from sharepoint. My initial idea was to use Image.Network() using a public link of the photo (but this is not viable, with drive from google no problem).

Can this be done with NetworkImage using credentials?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What errors do you get? Why'd you need credentials if it's a public link?

Comment: When I use image.Network("public link sharepoint") it throws an exception that says that the url provided it's not a photo. That's why i'm trying NetWorkImage with credentials...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access images from google drive which having no public URL then it will result in an error.

What you will have to do is to provide an access token on the account to access them like this.

```
NetworkImage(imgUrl, headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer ${accessToken}"})
```

Comment: I'm working with sharepoint online, it's the same solution? With google drive there is no problem using Image.Network and a public link. Can you provide me example of using authorization in headers? (I only have user and password to connect the sharepoint site)